# JQuery not behaving itself

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Of course it's jQuery, and not my lack of understanding causing this issue, but just in case it is my incompetence, can someone please tell me how to return the text "Acme" within this tag?

```
<div class="grid-56" id="1005" style="border:solid 1px lightgray;">
    <div class="grid-20 bold">
        <a href="#" class="id_select_company" id="company_name_dialog">
            Acme
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't seem to work!

```
var company_name = $("#" + id).children($("#company_name_dialog")).html();
```

It produces

```
<a href="#" class="id_select_company" id="company_name_dialog">
    Acme
</a>
```

I don't want the anchor tag, just the text.

Comment: I found the solution.. this was the problem: children($("#company_name_dialog")) - it should've been children("#company_name_dialog") - me being st00pid :)

thanks everyone!

Comment: remember you can only have one element with the id "company_name_dialog" - looks llike this could be in a list with other elements which look the same.

Comment: I'm selecting the ID, by first selecting a unique ID, then drilling down. It's working, but is it bad practise? How should I do it then? I can't use classes because they're being used for styling (!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `find()`:

```
var company_name = $("#" + id).find("#company_name_dialog").html();
```

It should work with `children()` too but you shouldn't pass a jQuery object in it, but rather an expression, which in this case is `'#company_name_dialog'`.

Using `html()` or `text()` doesn't matter, as now your selecting the innards of the `<a>` which doesn't have any HTML in it. The result is same in both cases as `text()` just strips HTML markup from the contents. Using `text()` in conjunction with your original code would have worked, but that would have been a workaround and you wouldn't have known what the real problem was.

Comment: If `$("#" + id).find("#company_name_dialog")` and `$("#company_name_dialog")` are not the same then something is **seriously** wrong with the document!

Comment: Actually I had to change the syntax AND use find.  - Thanks tatu

Answer (score 3):

Try something more direct (especially since id attribute's should be unique with an HTML doc):

```
var company_name = $('#company_name_dialog').text();
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, with the `.text()` function:

```
$("#" + id).children($("#company_name_dialog")).text();
```